# Add Feedly featured image class "webfeedsFeaturedVisual" to featured images in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, feed, feedly

I would like to customize the way Feedly presents my website's RSS Feed ([here](http://wordsinthebucket.com/feed)), which is actually very poorly displayed.

I followed [their instructions](http://blog.feedly.com/2015/07/31/10-ways-to-optimize-your-feed-for-feedly/#more-6276) adding all the suggested markups; this way I managed to have the correct title, description, icon, logo, cover image, accent color and everything else.

However, in the abovementioned guide it's said that in order to have Feedly pick the correct featured image you have to add a webfeedsFeaturedVisual classname. How can I do that with all my featured images?

Thank you in advance. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to add a class to your featured image:

Edit the reference to call the featured image in your template:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', array( 'class'   => "zoomer-class attachment-post-thumbnail")); ?>
```

Change `zoomer-class` to your own class name.

More info here:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/featured-image-add-image-class?replies=4

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you @user45250. In which template? single.php?

Comment: That depends where you are showing your featured image. If you are calling it within a post, then edit "singe.php", while "page.php" edits page template.

Comment: if you are not sure which file to edit, use the second option to add a filter into your function.php Follow the instructions in the link I provided.

Comment: Thank you. The second option worked. Now my featured images have that class but unfortunately it doesn't work as expected. Feedly still fails to recognize them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I managed to let Feedly show the featured image through a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-images-for-rss-feeds/).

Thanks for your help.